# Combining two validations in jQuery for password field

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a signup form, and I am using a 3rd party library to validate the inputs. This library provides very nice and cool effects for validation, but I need to do another verification to make sure the password and confirm password are matching. how can I do that via jQuery? Here is my code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Retype Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password2" />
</div>
```

and jQuery part:

```
$('#registrationForm').formValidation({
    framework: 'bootstrap',
    fields: {
        password: {
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'The password is required'
                }
            }
        },
        password2: {
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'Password conformation is required'
                },
                equalTo: {
                    field: 'password',
                    message: 'The password cannot be the same as username'
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

What should I put instead of the question marks, to address my issue? Or maybe I am completely wrong with the syntax?

Comment: Where's the jQuery? What you have there is a nested object literal.

Comment: Are you using Validate.js ?

Comment: No I am using formvalidation.io

Comment: Carl Edwards: I mentioned part of the code, which is relevant to password fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shree/g7kd7ask/1/)

Html :

```
<form id="formCheckPassword">

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Retype Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="cfmPassword" id="cfmPassword" />
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

and Jquery Rules :

```
$("#formCheckPassword").validate({
   rules: {
     password: {
       required: true,
       minlength: 6,
       maxlength: 10,

     },

     cfmPassword: {
       equalTo: "#password",
       minlength: 6,
       maxlength: 10
     }


   },
   messages: {
     password: {
       required: "the password is required"

     }
   }

 });
```

**Update as per request :**

```
$('#RegistrationForm').formValidation({
    framework: 'bootstrap',
    fields: {
        password: {
            validators: {
                identical: {
                    field: 'confirmPassword',
                    message: 'The password and its confirm are not the same'
                }
            }
        },
        confirmPassword: {
            validators: {
                identical: {
                    field: 'password',
                    message: 'The password and its confirm are not the same'
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank's Shree. Can you please rewrite your code based on this code snippet?

    $('#registrationForm').formValidation({
        framework: 'bootstrap',
        fields: {
            pw: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The password is required'
                    }
                }
            },
            pw2: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Conformation is required'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see it working in that syntax. If you want to do it via jQuery (as you mentioned), you can simply check the values:

```
var password1 = $('input[name=password]').val();
var password2 = $('input[name=password2]').val();
var match = password1 == password2
```